# Django admin input text color is white instead of black

Tags: django, input, django-admin, django-cms

I am new to Django and I am facing this input text color problem in admin panel; Input text color is white instead of black.

How to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Kindly share relevant customized  admin.py file.

Comment: Might be worth looking at not including django cms admin style in your installed apps with django 3.2. The package hasn't been updated to work with the dark theme as far as I'm aware. There's an issue for it here; https://github.com/django-cms/djangocms-admin-style/issues/439